# Book recommendations for fluid dynamics self-study

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, education, aerodynamics

I have my bachelors degree in engineering science: computer science, option electrotechnic. I have a good understanding of basic mechanics and dynamics, calculus (differential equations).

The books I'm now having a look at are:

- [*Fox and McDonald's Introduction to Fluid Mechanics, 8th Edition*](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP001805.html)
- [*Fundamentals of Aerodynamics, John D. Anderson*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073398101)

What book do you recommend for studying fluid dynamics on my own and why?

Comment: Click and hold to interact with an interactive fluid simulation: http://git.amandaghassaei.com/FluidSimulation/

Answer (score 20):

The books you have mentioned, are written from an engineering point of view rather than physicist's. The following books are recommended:

- **Fluid dynamics For Physicists** by T. E. Faber (Introductory. Doesn't need more backgrounds than you mentioned)
- **An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics** by G. K. Batchelor (Introductory. Doesn't need more backgrounds than you mentioned)
- **Fluid Mechanics, Volume 6 of Course of Theoretical Physics** by Landau and Lifshitz (Advanced)

and also you may find the following book, with a more mathematical flavor, interesting: (I haven't seen this one myself)

- **A Mathematical Introduction to Fluid Mechanics** by Chorin and Marsden

Comment: Which book would you recommend for an undergraduate with theoretical physics major? And what are the differences between engineering and physics point of view?

Comment: The engineering and physics points of view in fluid mechanics are quite different: physicists are more concerned with the equations and the physics of a situation or how it can be generalized whereas engineers are understandably much more interested in flows in particular situations, for particular types of pipe, and so on.

Comment: This answer appears to be in breach of the resource recommendations policy as described above!