# Recommended text for hydrodynamic

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, education, continuum-mechanics

i wanna books for fluid dynamics that it used Hamiltonian and Lagrangian formalism.

and also to compared to Lagrangian and Eulerian picture.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the fluid dynamics volume of "Course of Theoretical Physics" by Landau & Lifshitz. You can find it here: https://archive.org/details/FluidMechanics

Comment: Mechanics of fluids by Massey?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71257/2451 and links therein.