# Crash course in fluid dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, education, magnetohydrodynamics

I am teaching myself magnetohydrodynamics and have never taken a class on fluid dynamics before. It seems like knowing some fluid dynamics will help me understand MHD faster, so I was looking for a short book, long article, etc that could help me get up to speed with the basics. Would love some recommendations.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71257/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic not really though since I am looking for a short book (a skim. Plus the answer you linked to do not explain why the books are good)

Comment: This question really is unanswerable. There is no such thing as a short book on fluid dynamics that teaches you all the things you need. Also, you didn't mention which of the flavours of MHD you are studying, which makes it even more difficult to select relevant background. Also,what is the background that you have? In physics, or electromagnetics? Or do you have a background in math? Are you familiar with the NS equations?