What are some good resources to learn fluid mechanics?
I know that there are a lot of resources out there to be explored and I have gone through several of them. What I want is some resource where fluid mechanics is treated,

from a geometric viewpoint,
Navier-Stokes equation as a nonlinear dynamical system and include some discussions on generic properties of the solutions that can be drawn from the equations (i.e., without solving it).

Suggestions about good books, online courses and/or some websites will be appreciated.
Note: I have a physics background, so I can't go through dry mathematical abstract arguments that much.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71257/2451 and links therein.
